# How to Access the List Indices

Tags: r, list, indexing, apply, lapply

I have a list of numbers (index positions really) like so:

```
> original
[[1]]
[1] 99 100

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

[[3]]
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56

[[4]]
 [1] 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86
```

I would like to return another list which replicates each of the indices of the original list according to the length of the sublists.  Specifically, the results should look something like:

```
> result
    [[1]]
    [1] 1 1
```

because 1 is the index of the original and its length is 2

```
    [[2]]
     [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

because 2 is the index of the original and its length is 26

```
    [[3]]
     [1]  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

because 3 is the index of the original and its length is 27
In my mind, as long as I can access the index position, it should look something like this:

```
lapply(original, function(x) rep(index(x), length(x)))
```

This fails because I apparently cannot access the index of the list within lapply in this way, nor any other way I have tried.

anybody out there done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `relist()` a vector of indices, using the original list as the skeleton.

```
relist(rep(seq_along(original), lengths(original)), original)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 2
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Data:

```
original <- list(1:3, 4:5, 1:8)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mapply` here to access the index as well as the list elements.

```
mapply(function(x, y) rep(x, length(y)), seq_along(original), original)

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Taking a different example as it is easy to reproduce.

**data**

```
original <- list(c(1:3), c(4, 5), c(1:8))

original
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

---

Few other options :

Using only `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(original), function(x) rep(x, length(original[[x]])))
```

---

and using `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
original %>% map2(.y=seq_along(original),~rep(.y,length(.x)))
```